# Which of these Bhairava shruti texts / Tantras are lost?

Tags: tantra, shaivism, agamas, kashmiri-shaivism, bhairava

The following is a list from the Shrikanthi Samhita of the 64 Bhairava Tantras and their 8 classifications:

> **Yamalasataka** - BrahmayAmala, VishnuyAmala, Rudra-yAmala, Swacanda
> yAmala, AtharvanayAmala, AdiyAmala, VetAla yAmala
>
> **Bhairavasataka** - Swacanda Bhairava, CanDa Bhairava, Krodhbhairava,
> AsitAngabhairava, MahochawAsa bhairava, KapAliSa bhairava
>
> **Mattasatka** - Rakta, Lampata, LakSmi, KAlikA, PingaLA, Utphullaka,
> VimbAdha
>
> **Mangalastka** - Picu, Bhairavi, Brahmi, KalA, VijayA, CandrA, MangalA
> and Sarva mangalA.
>
> **Cakrastka** - Mantracakra, Varnacakra, Sakti Cankra, KalA chakra, Vindu
> Chakra, NAdachakra, Guhya Cakra and PurNa Cakra.
>
> **Baharupastka** - Andhaka, Rudrabheda, Arja, VarNabheda, Yama, Vidanga,
> Matrrodana and JAlima.
>
> **Vagishastka** - Bhairavi, CitrikA, HimsA, KadambikA, HrllekhA,
> CandralekhA, VidyullekhA, VidvanmAtA.
>
> **Shikastka** - Bhairavisikha, VinAshikha, VinAmani, Sammoha, DAmara,
> Atharvaka, Kabandha and Shirshceda.

How many more Bhairava Tantras are there which claim to be part of this list? Where can these texts be found?